Flutter - TextField with TextAlign.right doesn´t show spaces
I have a TextField with TextAlign.right. If i write some text in it and press the space bar multiple times the spaces are not displayed, until i enter another "visible" character.
How to display the spaces without entering a "visible" character after?


I found a solution to this problem. Hope it helps others.
If the space get´s replaced with \u00A0 it works like intended.
onChanged: (value) {
              String newText = value.replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0');
              widget.textEditingController.value = widget.textEditingController.value.copyWith(
                text: newText,
              );
            }


Just set the text direction to right-to-left:
textAlign: TextAlign.right,
textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, 

And it will work.

TextDirection.rtl didn´t work.
